# Logical Modeling difficulty

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I have a task to design a simple database that will store information about restaurants, customers and Categories that each restorant falls in (ex. American,Indian...). The problem is that I am not sure how to model the database having the fact that every customer may have zero or more registered other
customers as friends. Whilst a customer can have many friend connections, for 
each friend connection the date must be recorded.
I assume that I have to create another table called Friends that will contain the cust_id,data as attributes.

My tables are:

```
Restaurants(rest_id,name,address,date_opened,income_cat_id*)
Category(car_id,title,Description)
Customers(cust_id,name,address,DOB,Mobile_number)
```

Here is my ER Diagram, but as I said I am not sure if the Recursive relation is right for my Customers table:

[image: Here is the ER diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need another table to model the connections, something like:

```
Connection(cust_id1, cust_id2, connectdate)
```

Comment: Agreed. You could toss a relationship/friend/connection id in there too, or just use cust_id1, cust_id2 as the key. No reason to over think this. Just don't try to stick the relationship in the `customers` table. That's just a very bad no good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a very much!
Does that mean that I have to have the following constraints in the Connection table?

```
CONSTRAINT pk_Connections PRIMARY KEY (cust_id1,cust_id2),
CONSTRAINT fk_Customers_Connections_cust_id1 FOREIGN KEY (cust_id1) REFERENCES Customers(cust_id)
                                                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_Customers_Connections_cust_id2 FOREIGN KEY (cust_id2) REFERENCES Customers(cust_id)
                                                ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```